# Convert data frame to JSON with single-element arrays

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

Let's say I have this data:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
```

A simple `toJSON` gets me this:

```
[{"value":"foo"},{"value":"bar"},{"value":"baz"}]
```

But if I need the values as single element arrays, how do I structure the original data? I've tried a few variations involving `c()`, `list()`, and `I()`. Nothing works to get me this output:

```
[{"value":["foo"]},{"value":["bar"]},{"value":["baz"]}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the arrangement you want, you need a list of lists

```
jsonlite::toJSON(list(list("value"="foo"), list("value"="bar"), list("value"="baz")))
# [{"value":["foo"]},{"value":["bar"]},{"value":["baz"]}]
```

We can do this with a little help from the tidyverse function `mutate_all` to convert all the columns to lists.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_all(as.list) %>% jsonlite::toJSON()
# [{"value":["foo"]},{"value":["bar"]},{"value":["baz"]}]
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning in your answer that to change just the `value` column, use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_all`: `df %>% mutate_at(vars(value), as.list) %>% jsonlite::toJSON()`.

Comment: The list of lists is the more attractive solution but it seemed to have the opposite problem; it converted every value to an array. (The data in the question is just a stripped down test case, I do have a couple of columns.) I was able to get around this with some use of `I()` and setting `auto_unbox` to true.

Comment: You can control how which values do not get wrapped in an array with `unbox`. It's always easier to help with a more realistic example.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass list to `toJSON` function.

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- data.frame(value = c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
# Iterate over rows and put them to list
# Output passed to toJSON output
toJSON(apply(df, 1, as.list))
# [{"value":["foo"]},{"value":["bar"]},{"value":["baz"]}]
```

Like this `toJSON` input is:

```
apply(df, 1, as.list)

[[1]]
[[1]]$value
[1] "foo"

[[2]]
[[2]]$value
[1] "bar"

[[3]]
[[3]]$value
[1] "baz"
```

Comment: The only caveat is that `apply` converts the data.frame to a matrix so if you have columns of different datatypes, this might get messy. But for the simple case in the question where there is just one column, this is very nice.

Comment: Yeah the question included a pretty stripped down test case, but this looks promising. Seems odd that there's no way for `toJSON` to treat the data as it's presented.